# Change Array initialization based on Input Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d Boolean array and I want to dynamically create it's size based on the input coming in.
For example: I have this string as the input "0-1 0-2 1-2 1-3 2-3". I split it on the dash and parsed it to an int. All those coordinates are positions in the Boolean array. When I initialize the array below for this example it works. But how could I initialize it dynamically in case the input changes?

```
myArray = new boolean [4][4];
```

Comment: After splitting , you can have the max position from the coordinates. Based on this declare your array size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must use a fixed-size array, you could find the `max` values for each coordinate separately, and use these values for the initialization:

```
int maxR = 0, maxC = 0;
for (String pair : pairs) {
    int r = ... // first part of the split
    int c = ... // second part of the split
    maxR = Math.max(maxR, r);
    maxC = Math.max(maxC, c);
}
boolean[][] myArray = new boolean[maxR][maxC];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ArrayLists instead. You can grow them as needed. (It's harder to shrink them.)

Answer (score 0):

split the string on space , " "
It will give you total number of coordinates.

```
   String[] splitted = "0-1 0-2 1-2 1-3 2-3".split(" ");
```

Iterate through the array, split on "-" and get the maxX and maxY.
This will give you the dimensions of the array.

The declaration will be like

```
boolean[][] myArray = new boolean[maxX][maxY];
```

Hope it helps